# How can I bundle additional files with `NodejsFunction`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I would like to upload an additional Html file to the code source like below.
[image]

this is my code:

```
const mailerFunction = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'ApiNotificationHandler', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    memorySize: 1024,
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(3),
    handler: 'main',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/mailer/index.ts'),
    environment: {
        SES_REGION,
        SES_EMAIL_FROM,
        SES_EMAIL_TO,
    }
});
```

I use a CDK 2.58.1 version.
How could I upload additional html file to code source with cdk lambda?

Answer (score 8):

Copy the `.html` file by defining a [commandHook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#command-hooks) in the `bundling` prop:

```js
new NodejsFunction(this, "ApiNotificationHandler", {
  bundling: {
    commandHooks: {
      afterBundling: (inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] => [
        `cp ${inputDir}/path/from/root/to/email-template.html ${outputDir}`,
      ],
      beforeBundling: (inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] => [],
      beforeInstall: (inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] => [],
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

The interface requires all three hooks to be defined.  Choose one to implement the copying. Return an empty array as a no-op for the other two.  `inputDir` will be the project root directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [command hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#command-hooks).
In Your example it would probably look like this (adjust the `inputDir` command):

```js
const mailerFunction = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'ApiNotificationHandler', {
    bundling: {
      commandHooks: {
        beforeBundling(inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] {
          return [`cp -r ${inputDir} ${outputDir}`] //adjust here
        },
        afterBundling(inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] {
          return []
        },
        beforeInstall(inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] {
          return []
        },
      },
    },
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    memorySize: 1024,
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(3),
    handler: 'main',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/mailer/index.ts'),
    environment: {
        SES_REGION,
        SES_EMAIL_FROM,
        SES_EMAIL_TO,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also bundle files using the `loader` options and regular import in the handler code. Here is the updated code.

```
const mailerFunction = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'ApiNotificationHandler', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    memorySize: 1024,
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(3),
    handler: 'main',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/mailer/index.ts'),
    environment: {
        SES_REGION,
        SES_EMAIL_FROM,
        SES_EMAIL_TO,
    },
    bundling: {
      loader: { '.png': 'file', '.html': 'file' },
      //minify: true,
      // sourceMap: true,
      // externalModules: ['aws-sdk', '@aws-sdk'],
    },
});
```

Now inside your `path.join(__dirname, '../../src/mailer/index.ts')` file, you can just import the files like this.

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs';

import template from './email-template.html';
import logo from './logo.png';


const templateContent = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(template)).toString('utf-8');
const logoContent = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(logo));
```

For more info see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-nodejs.NodejsFunctionProps.html#example

Comment: Thanks for this. I can confirm that I used this approach and it works.  Had to include a type for html and the `import indexHtml from './index.html'` did the trick.