# How to deploy an AWS Lambda function using AWS CDK when it is located outside the CDK folder?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I had the following structure of my node.js (express) application before I decided to move it to the AWS Cloud.

```
project/
  src/
    controllers/
      test/
        test.controller.ts
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 tsconfig.json
```

I've chosen to use AWS CDK for provisioning my resources through code. I initialized AWS CDK within the `cdk/` folder of my existing project.

The updated structure is as follows:

```
project/
  cdk/ <- New folder
    bin/
      cdk.ts
    lib/
      cdk-stack.ts
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    tsconfig.json
src/
  controllers/
    test/
      test.controller.ts
package.json
package-lock.json
tsconfig.json
```

In my `cdk-stack.ts` I tried to provision AWS Gateway with a lambda function

```js
import { Stack, StackProps, aws_apigatewayv2, aws_lambda_nodejs, aws_lambda } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { HttpLambdaIntegration } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations";
import { Code } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import * as path from "path";

export class CdkStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const apiGateway = new aws_apigatewayv2.HttpApi(this, "ApiGateway", {
      apiName: "ApiGateway",
    });

    const helloWorldLambdaFunction = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, "HelloWorldLambdaFunction", {
      entry: path.join(__dirname, "../../src/controllers/test/hello-world.lambda.ts"), // <- The line of code that bothers me
      handler: "helloWorldHandler",
      runtime: aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      architecture: aws_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
    });

    apiGateway.addRoutes({
      path: "/hello-world",
      methods: [aws_apigatewayv2.HttpMethod.GET],
      integration: new HttpLambdaIntegration("hello-world-integration", helloWorldLambdaFunction),
    });
  }
}
```

To reduce the amount of refactoring needed, I plan to place my new Lambda code alongside the controller's code. The new structure looks like this:

```
project/
  cdk/ 
    bin/
      cdk.ts
    lib/
      cdk-stack.ts
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    tsconfig.json
src/
  controllers/
    test/
      hello-world.lambda.ts <- New file added here
      test.controller.ts
package.json
package-lock.json
tsconfig.json
```

When I run the `cdk deploy` command to deploy my stack it shows an error

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "/src/controllers/test/hello-world.lambda.ts"
```

After researching, I assumed that [`aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html) cannot deploy source code located outside the CDK directory, as is the case with my file.

This assumption was confirmed when I placed my file next to `cdk-stack.ts` in the `lib/` folder, resulting in a successful deployment.

Moreover, I found a property named [`projectRoot`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#projectroot), which allows redirection to the `project/` folder. Once redirected, it began deploying Lambda files outside the `cdk/` folder.

```js
// cut

const helloWorldLambdaFunction = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, "HelloWorldLambdaFunction", {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "../../src/controllers/test/hello-world.lambda.ts"),
  handler: "helloWorldHandler",
  runtime: aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  architecture: aws_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
  projectRoot: path.join(__dirname, "../../"), // <- This prop added
});

// cut
```

My questions are:

1. Is it acceptable to have a structure where the CDK folder is created inside my project?
2. Is it advisable to modify the [`projectRoot`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#projectroot) property to point to the parent folder, enabling the deployment of Lambda functions located outside the `cdk/` folder?
3. Is there a better method to deploy Lambda files situated outside the `cdk/` folder? I aim to restrict my `cdk/` folder solely for resource provisioning, keeping all project resources outside to avoid clutter.

Comment: some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147158/how-can-i-bundle-additional-files-with-nodejsfunction

Comment: Hey, thanks! But it seems like an overkill for such a simple problem :(

Comment: also you can use it as an asset: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/serverless_example.html

Comment: The suggested/idiomatic approach is to have your runtime code alongside your CDK code. The line between them should not be very strict.